# How to determine number of objects in one-to-many relationship in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

So, I've got a one-to-many relationship of Companies to Employees in CoreData (using a SQLite backend on iOS, if that's relevant). I want to create a predicate that only returns Companies that have 0 Employees associated with them. I could do it by getting *all* the Companies and iterating over them, but that would be (I assume) much slower.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
-Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying @falconcreek's answer and getting an error (described in my comment on his answer), I did some googling and determined that the answer was

```
NSPredicate *noEmployeesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employees.@count == 0"];
```

Now everything works über efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: excellent. I was looking for the @count function in the docs. it is still worthwhile to check for nil relationships as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Company -> Employee relationship is named "employees"

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

// the following doesn't work
// NSPredicate *noEmployeesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employees = nil OR employees[SIZE] = 0"];

// use @count instead
NSPredicate *noEmployeesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employees = nil OR employees.@count == 0"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I ran it, I got `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'`

This led to some googling, which turned up the result that I posted as the answer. I think the problem is that I'm using a one-to-many relationship.
Anyways, much thanks!